# Regex matches but .scan returns nil

Tags: ruby, regex

As you can [see on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/GiCdJOF3wd) the regexp `<p( style=".+"){0,1}>.+<\/p>` matches the string `<p>aasdad</p>`.

But, when I do `"<p>sdasdasd</p>".scan(/<p( style=".+"){0,1}>.+<\/p>/)` I get `[[nil]]`. Why the matched string is not included in the return value?

Comment: Heh just use `?` instead of `{0,1}`. Also, what do you expect ? The group is not matched there and since it's optional the whole expression does match, thus the "matched" group returns nill

Comment: I also suggest not trying to parse HTML with regexes. Use an HTML parser like Nokogiri.

Comment: @JoeHalfFace most often you don't know the data you'll be getting. For example, your regex will fail if the `p`aragraph has other attributes as well. Even if you know some regex will match what it should, you can never ensure it won't match something it shouldn't, such as `<p></p>` in `<script> $("a").append("$<p></p>")</script>` or in `<a title="<p></p>">`. The latter is not valid HTML but it doesn't mean it won't occur in your data. Also, some people like not to escape HTML in `textarea`s. Also, `<pre>` is fun.

Comment: @JanDvorak, this is to refactor some of redactor.js output server side, actually, it has very limited nubmer of options

Comment: @JoeHalfFace I'd still go for Nokogiri. You never know what version changes bring. Scraping HTML is always prone to failing due to HTML changes. Using DOM reduces the risk somewhat. Using DOM with good  selectors reduces the risk significantly.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/182705

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the way `scan` works. From the Ruby [documentation for `scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

> If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an
>   array containing one entry per group.

Since the optional group `( style=".+")` doesn't match you get only a `nil` in the result. You can use `(?:` for a non-capturing group:

```
"<p>sdasdasd</p>".scan(/<p(?: style=".+"){0,1}>.+<\/p>/)
# => ["<p>sdasdasd</p>"]
```

Comment: @Joe Half Face - apparently you hadn't, or else you wouldn't have needed to ask.

Comment: @pguardiario, after I asked question there was sudden idea)

Comment: @Joe Half Face - maybe you should have considered the problem longer before posting then. You just earned a downvote from me.

Comment: @pguardiario, I don't know, man, may be you can manage the time you understand things in seconds scale or forecast future, not everyone can.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with .match

```
"<p>sdasdasd</p>".match(/<p( style=".+"){0,1}>.+<\/p>/)
# => <p>sdasdasd</p>
```

Comment: Not really, `match` returns a `MatchData` object, not a string, you should do `"...".match(/.../)[0]` to get the matched string.

Comment: @toro2k, or just use String#[] like most people.

Comment: `MatchData` also exposes a `#captures` instance method which will return any captured MatchData.